# Astyanax getKey with compound key

Tags: cassandra, counter, astyanax, cql3, compound-key

I would like to run the following code with a compound primary key.

```
Column<String> result = keyspace.prepareQuery(CF_COUNTER1)
    .getKey(rowKey)
    .getColumn("Column1")
    .execute().getResult();
Long counterValue = result.getLongValue();
```

Research seems to show that it can be a string that represents a key (if it's not a compound primary key).  [The documentation](http://netflix.github.io/astyanax/javadoc/com/netflix/astyanax/query/ColumnFamilyQuery.html) says that it is of type `K`, alas, I am not very experience with Java, and have no idea what that means.  Is it just a base type that lots of stuff inherits from?  If so, I'm not really any closer to knowing what `getKey(K)` needs in order to handle a compound key (am I?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write a class that fits the columns in your data model. You can then give this class to Astyanax in your mutations or queries.

For example, if you had a data model like this

```
   CREATE TABLE fishblogs (
        userid varchar,
        when timestamp,
        fishtype varchar,
        blog varchar,
        image blob,
        PRIMARY KEY (userid, when, fishtype)
    );
```

you would create a class like this:

```
   public class FishBlog {
      @Component(ordinal = 0)
      public long when;
      @Component(ordinal = 1)
      public String fishtype;
      @Component(ordinal = 2)
      public String field;

      public FishBlog() {
      }
   }
```

*When* and *fishtype* form your composite column key and are represented by the *FishBlog* class. Userid would be your row/partition key and can be of the simple "string" type.

Have a look at [this blog explaining in great detail](http://brianoneill.blogspot.de/2012/10/cql-astyanax-and-compoundcomposite-keys.html) how to insert data with composite keys (where I took this example from).

Hope that helps.